# dynamically add folder to ignore when using npm publish

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I have a static `.npmignore` file with

```
foo
bar
baz
```

in it. When I publish to NPM, the contents in those 3 dirs will be ignored.

My question is, is there a way to dynamically add a folder to ignore when using `npm publish` at the command line?

Something like:

```
npm publish --ignore=.r2g
```

here we can ignore a folder called `.r2g`

Here are [the npm-publish docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish)

Comment: There's nothing builtin to achieve this that I'm aware of. You can utilize npm-scripts `prepublish` (or `prepublishOnly`) hook to append folder to _.npmignore_. E.g. `"prepublish": "echo \".r2g\" >>.npmignore"`. Then use `postpublish` hook to remove the previously appended folder from _.npmignore_, effectively resetting it.  E.g. `"postpublish": "cat .npmignore | tail -r | tail -n +2 | tail -r >.npmignore"` - this removes the last line. For cross-platform support consider invoking _nodejs_ scripts containing similar logic from the  `prepublish`/ `postpublish` hooks.

Comment: Another way is [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) to create tarball, (instead of `npm publish`), and use a `postpack` script in _pkg.json_. The node script `postpack` invokes can utilize [node-tar](https://github.com/npm/node-tar) to effectively **1.** Unpack tarball. **2.** Remove unwanted dir(s). **3.** Create new tarball. (Analogous to [this example](https://github.com/matt-block/react-native-in-app-browser/blob/master/scripts/postpack.ts)). This way you can also omit redundant `postpack` script and `node-tar` devDependency from _pkg.json_, leaving no trace in what's published.

Comment: @RobC that is a good idea although a bit intrusive, tbh i prob wont do it that way but i will think abou it

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree about it being intrusive - hence comment only. Unfortunately, all solutions I can think of  entail some kind of _"pre/post"_ npm-script hook -  (`npm pack` being my most preferred).

Answer (score 5):

First, a static solution:

You can include a `.npmignore` file per directory that you want to exclude.
As the [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) states:

> Like git, npm looks for .npmignore and .gitignore files in all subdirectories of your package, not only the root directory.

I created an example of this in https://github.com/dral/npmignore-example (and the corresponding package `npmignore-example`).

file structure
    index.js
    .npmignore
    bar/index.js
    baz/index.js
    foo/index.js
       /.npmignore

the root .npmignore removes only the baz directory. the nested foo/.npmignore removes all content (from this point on).

The installed package includes only

```
index.js
bar/index.js
```

In order to do so dynamically you can use a script that adds and then removes a simple `.npmignore` file in the selected folder(s).

```
echo '*' > .r2g/.npmignore && npm publish && rm .r2g/.npmignore
```

Then if you need to automate this, consider using `prepublish` and `postpublish` scripts that take into account an env variable so you can use something like `NPM_IGNORE=.r2g npm publish`.

Hope this helps.